# What is the fastest mosaic image blending algorithm?

Tags: computer-vision, linear-algebra, blending, panoramas, image-stitching

I'm recently working on building panoramas from a large number of mosaic images where the luminance varies among virtually all of them. Therefore, I have to devise an algorithm to blend the images (can be assumed to be well aligned) in each panorama to remove the seams between adjacent tiles. According to Perez's paper (https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall07/Papers/Perez03.pdf) I've developed a program that works well, but the critical issue is that it is too computationally expensive. Blending each pair of images takes 10~15 minutes to solve the Poisson Equation, while each tile in my panorama is 2048*2448 in size; there are around 100 tiles in each panorama, and totally 4500 panoramas to be built, so the method is definitely unfeasible. In view of the large amount of data, speed is virtually everything, so I've been looking for an algorithm (gradient domain, optimal seam, etc, but not alpha blending since it's not very effective) that is most efficient for blending large images. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What about Laplace pyramid blending.

Look at
https://compvisionlab.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/image-blending-using-pyramid/

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that looks good. I'm also looking at this one right now.